# How do I keep newest DISQUS comments on top?

Tags: disqus

When someone votes up a comment, it moves to the top of the comments list. However, I want to keep the comments chronological. How can I do that?

Comment: Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 1):

Disqus 2012 gives you the option to sort the comments. Click on the drop down next to *Discussion* and select how you want comments to be sorted.

[image]